Algorithm Divide and Conquer Maximum Subarray
An IT company wants to perform an analysis of revenues and expenses in a period of n months. The information is given in a list A[1], . . . , A[n] with integer values.
In month i the company had a deficit or surplus which corresponds to someone positive or negative integer in position A[i]. The goal is to find a continuous interval of months with the maximum total profit for the company. Here are three examples:

(aʹ) A = [30, −50, 20, −50], where the interval with maximum total profit is from month
1 until month 1, with a profit of 30,

(bʹ) A = [30, −5, 20, −50], where the interval with maximum total profit is from month
1 until month 3 with a total profit equal to 45,

(cʹ) A = [30, −50, 20, −5, 40], where the interval with maximum total profit is from
month 3 up to month 5 with a total profit equal to 55.


Design an efficient divide and conquer algorithm. To analyze for correctness and complexity, describing and solving the retro-bit relation that expresses the time complexity of your algorithm.
I divided by 2 until each array had only one element. Then I found the max but don't know how to find the number of the months.

For each interval, you can calculate the maximum sum from a prefix of the current interval, the maximum sum from a suffix of the current interval, and the overall maximum sum of a subarray contained in the current interval.
The overall best result for a larger interval will either be entirely contained in the left part (the overall best of solving the left interval), entirely contained in the right part (the overall best of solving the right interval), or span both halves (being the sum of the maximum suffix sum of the left part and the maximum prefix sum of the right part).
Sample implementation in C++ (assuming that the empty subarray is not a valid answer):
#include <algorithm>
#include <span>
#include <numeric>
struct Result {
    int prefixBest, suffixBest, overallBest, sum;
};
Result solve(std::span<int> nums) {
    if (nums.size() == 1) return {nums[0], nums[0], nums[0], nums[0]};
    auto leftPart = nums.subspan(0, nums.size() / 2), rightPart = nums.subspan(nums.size() / 2);
    auto leftRes = solve(leftPart), rightRes = solve(rightPart);
    return {
        std::max(leftRes.prefixBest, leftRes.sum + rightRes.prefixBest),
        std::max(rightRes.suffixBest, rightRes.sum + leftRes.suffixBest),
        std::max({leftRes.overallBest, rightRes.overallBest, leftRes.suffixBest + rightRes.prefixBest}),
        leftRes.sum + rightRes.sum
    };
}
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main() {
    std::vector v{30, -50, 20, -5, 40};
    std::cout << solve(v).overallBest << '\n'; // 55
}

This technique is more useful on a dynamic array with range queries and updates.

Approach
This solution is in Ruby. Two hashes are maintained. When traversing the given array:

continuing, has keys :start_period and :value, the value of :value being the current sum of array values from the index :start_period to the index of the current period;
previous_best, has the same two keys as continuing plus the key :end_period, and represents the best interval found so far.
continuing is converted to an empty hash when its value of :value goes negative; and
previous_best is returned by the method best_interval.

Ruby Code
def best_interval(arr)
  continuing    = {}  # empty hash
  previous_best = {}  # empty hash   
  arr.each_with_index do |x,i|
    continuing = { start_period: i, value: 0 } if continuing.empty?
    continuing[:value] += x
    if previous_best.empty? ||
      (continuing[:value] > previous_best[:value])
      previous_best.update(continuing)
      previous_best[:end_period] = i
    end
    continuing.clear if continuing[:value] < 0
  end
  previous_best
end

Notes on Ruby code

continuing[:value] += x is effectively the same as continuing[:value] = continuing[:value] + x
previous_best.update(continuing) merges continuing into previous_best, modifying previous_best in place
|| signifies "or"
continuing.clear removes all key-value pairs from continuing

Examples
best_interval [-1, 2, 3, 1, -4, 5, -2]
  #=> {:start_period=>1, :value=>7, :end_period=>5}

best_interval [-1, 2, 3, 1, -5, 4, -2]
  #=> {:start_period=>1, :value=>6, :end_period=>3}

best_interval [1, 2, 3, -1, -5, 5, -2]
  #=> {:start_period=>0, :value=>6, :end_period=>2}

best_interval [-1, -2, -3, 1, -5, -4, -2]
  #=> {:start_period=>3, :value=>1, :end_period=>3}

best_interval [-1, -2, -3]
  #=> {:start_period=>0, :value=>-1, :end_period=>0}

